# Removing certain core Gutenberg blocks, allowed_block_types not working

Tags: gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to remove core blocks that won't work with my custom theme. I tried using allowed_block_types, but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried using the code in my functions that I found at developer.wordpress.org, but it does not work for me:

```
function wpdocs_allowed_block_types ( $block_editor_context, $editor_context ) {
    if ( ! empty( $editor_context->post ) ) {
        return array(
            'core/paragraph',
            'core/heading',
            'core/list',
        );
    }
 
    return $block_editor_context;
}
 
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types_all', 'wpdocs_allowed_block_types', 10, 2 );
```

Does anyone have a solution?
Am I missing a function?

Comment: That code snippet works for me as expected - the paragraph, heading, and the list block are the only ones that are available in the block editor... Are you sure that you have placed it in the current theme's code base or if it's inside a plugin, that the plugin is activated?

Comment: Thank you for your response!!!. I just adding again to my functions.php file and it worked this time. I think where I placed it made a difference. I placed it forward the top before the setup and it worked.